# Thunderbolt displays

Tags: display, thunderbolt-display

Besides the thunderbolt displays by Apple, are there any other monitor manufacturers that make monitors with thunderbolt interfaces? I could only find the Apple thunderbolt displays and 1-2 models from LG.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.amazon.co.uk/monitor-thunderbolt/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Amonitor%20thunderbolt

Comment: Looked at the link, the first choice was excellent, but it is not thunderbolt capable. Besides the few models from LG, there were no other alternatives (at least I didn't find any).

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for actual thunderbolt connections so you can daisy chain devices? Or just looking to avoid using a dongle to connect to a monitor? If so any display port monitor will work with a mini-dp to dp cable.

Comment: I'm looking for a cheaper alternative to the Apple thunderbolt displays. I have a thunderbolt dock that I want to attach dual monitors to. The problem is, one of the monitors has to be "thunderbolt ready", i.e. connected via a thunderbolt cable to the dock. When connected with an adapter, you cannot have two active displays connected to the dock. So yeah, I'm looking for actual thunderbolt connections.